# why java: package io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin does not exist?

Tags: flutter

When doing a build project in Intellij I get an error in GeneratedPluginRegistrant, cannot resolve GoogleSignInPlugin.

I followed directions at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#-installing-tab-

My pubspec.yaml: (I tried with and without ^).

```
dependencies:   google_sign_in: "^3.0.5"   flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

flutter doctor

> Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale
>   en-US) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android
>   SDK 28.0.2) [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
>   [✓] Android Studio (version 3.1) [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
>   (version 2018.2.2)

Comment: I created a brand new project, and only added google_sign_in: "^3.0.5" to pubspec.yaml. And yes, I did a packages get. But same error.

Comment: I wonder if Flutter devs simply don't click Build Project? I followed the example at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bROui4ID9_Q to see if I missed anything. I did not, so I think Flutter devs don't click Build Project??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we can ignore the build errors. Something I don't like, but everything works ok. Even building the apk on the command-line with 'flutter build apk'. https://flutter.io/android-release/

Dart isn't built like Android, so no need to build project when developing. However, the "cannot find plugin" error is a Java classpath error, just need to add to the classpath.

IntelliJ folks could probably do it for us.